Call to a member function diffInSeconds() on null in laravel
that error happens after I use the browser several times
Call to a member function diffInSeconds() on null
    
  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:288
    284▕                 [$date, $time] = explode(' ', $formattedStartedAt);
    285▕
    286▕                 $this->output->write("  $date $time");
    287▕
  ➜ 288▕                 $runTime = $this->getDateFromLine($line)->diffInSeconds($startDate);
    289▕
    290▕                 if ($file) {
    291▕                     $this->output->write($file = " $file");
    292▕                 }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Traits\EnumeratesValues.php:240
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console\{closure}()

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:248
      Illuminate\Support\Collection::each()

How can I set the $startDat??
I found this code in servecommand.php
[$startDate, $file] = $this->requestsPool[$requestPort]; $formattedStartedAt = $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Considering this is in the vendor folder and one of the framework files, I would not put any permanent changes in it, since it will get overridden next time you run an update. However, you can add logging in the file to figure out what's going on.

Actually, I don't think it has anything to do with $startDate, since it's saying diffInSeconds on null, which means the Carbon instance being returned from getDateFromLine($line) is null.

Kindly check whether you have included use statement for Carbon & DateTIme Like use Carbon\Carbon;
use DateTime;

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

ok,I was using laravel10 then I started a new project laravel11 and I copied ServeCommand.php from the project and replaced it in my current project,the problem seems to be solved .hope that wouldn't cause new one.
